# Why doesn't git pull restore files I've deleted from my working directory?

Tags: git

I Have a problem with git 
My problem is the following, when I make a pull:

```
git pull origin example
```

Until there Perfect!!, Then I make a

```
rm -Rf rootdirectory
```

Then

```
git commit -am "Delete files"
```

and Then again I make a pull because I need this files

```
git pull origin example
```

but it isn't get again the rootdirectory

This is a message:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

How I can do for get the files with git pull again?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, really - you deleted the files, and committed that change. Why do you expect a pull to return a different result? =)

Comment: I'm beginning with git, but if I deleted files and then I make a commit in my local repository, until that i not do a push the pull
tods should bring me the remote branch files. This is so?

Comment: @MarceloPrueba Absolutely not ;-) See my answer

Comment: Christoph, thanks!
Now I have all files again!, Are you have some link for learn more about git?

Comment: @MarceloPrueba if you have a github repository, this should be an awesome interactive tutorial: http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason git pull does not change anything is that you are not pulling **data** from the remote repository, you are pulling **changes**. And there are no changes for git to pull!

Git is not a data store. It's a *version control system*

However, if you want to *checkout* the previous state you can easily do that:

```
git checkout HEAD~1
```

This means you are resetting your working copy to the previous state before the latest commit.

If however, you would like to completely remove the commit that deleted the files, you can do that as well:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 3):

Am I right in thinking that you're used to Subversion, where if you deleted the files, and then did a `svn update`, the files would get repopulated?  Me, too.

In git, you have to do `git checkout` to bring files out of the repo.  You can also use `git reset --hard` to update the files, but doing so will wipe out any changes in the working directory.

Comment: Thank's Lester!, I'm wont to used svn!

Comment: I too want to use SVN! Git is not user-friendly. People see fancy-ness in complex things whether that is bringing value in proportion or not. But the real challenge is to make things simpler not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way git works. After pulling `origin/example` and committing your change ("Delete files") your local repo is ahead of `origin/master` by that 1 commit:

```
A---B---C  origin/master
         \
          D  master
```

Where `D` is your `Delete files` commit. Another `git pull` gives you `Already up-to-date` because there are no new commits on `origin/master` that could be pulled into your local repo.

To "get the files again", you can either undo you last commit:

```
git checkout HEAD~1
```

Or you can *reset* your local repository to match the remote repository:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory where the files are deleted, make sure you are on the branch you want and type "git checkout ."  this will bring back the files you deleted on your current branch.